# how to add a method to all controller by default in laravel?

Tags: laravel

i want to add new method to each controller that created by artisan command
for example if i run "php artisan make:controller BookController"
then i want that BookController file has a method named 'details' by default
any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel uses "stubs" when creating new models/controllers/migrations etc using `php artisan make:...`.

Run `php artisan stub:publish` to publish the default stubs into a `/stubs/` folder in your project. You can then easily customize those stubs to your liking.

[Stub Customization](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#stub-customization)

Comment: Then you will have multiple declaration of the same method in all your controllers. @Miladpegah solution is more suited.

Comment: @N69S "_i want to add new method to each controller that created by artisan command_" That's what OP wants

Comment: @N69S Guess it depends on what OP really wants. OP didn't specify if they want the method named "details" to have the same functionality in all controllers or if they just want to have a "scaffold" for that method like you get when creating a Resource Controller. Those already have "blank" `index`, `create`, `edit` etc methods.

Answer (score 2):

All controllers extends `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` class.
add your method to controller(`App\Http\Controllers\Controller.php`) and use that in all your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to write your own custom `make` command to achieve it. There is a link I found that might help you - https://medium.com/@imfx/create-make-custom-commands-in-laravel-9fa002da582e.

Basically, you will need to overwrite `make:controller` and use your own stub.